# Spring Boot + Hibernate + JPA + Postgres Multi tenant App unable to persist entity

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, multi-tenant

I am building a Multitenant saas application using single database with multiple schema; one schema per client. I am using Spring Boot 2.1.5, Hibernate 5.3.10 with compatible spring data jpa and postgres 11.2.

I have followed this blogpost https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-hibernate-multitenancy-implementation.

Tried debugging the code, below are my findings: 
* For the default schema provided in the datasource configuration, hibernate properly validates schema. It creates the tables/entity in the default schema which are missing or new. 
* Tenant Identifier is properly resolved and hibernate builds a session using this tenant.

I have uploaded the code in below repo :

https://github.com/naveentulsi/multitenant-lithium

Some important classes I have added here.

```
    @Component
    @Log4j2
    public class MultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl implements 
       MultiTenantConnectionProvider {

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    public Connection getAnyConnection() throws SQLException {
        return dataSource.getConnection();
    }

    @Override
    public void releaseAnyConnection(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
        connection.close();
    }

    @Override
    public Connection getConnection(String tenantIdentifier) throws SQLException {
        final Connection connection = getAnyConnection();
        try {
            if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(tenantIdentifier)) {
                String setTenantQuery = String.format(AppConstants.SCHEMA_CHANGE_QUERY, tenantIdentifier);
                connection.createStatement().execute(setTenantQuery);
                final ResultSet resultSet = connection.createStatement().executeQuery("select current_schema()");
                if(resultSet != null){
                    final String string = resultSet.getString(1);
                    log.info("Current Schema" + string);
                }
                System.out.println("Statement execution");
            } else {
                connection.createStatement().execute(String.format(AppConstants.SCHEMA_CHANGE_QUERY, AppConstants.DEFAULT_SCHEMA));
            }
        } catch (SQLException se) {
            throw new HibernateException(
                    "Could not change schema for connection [" + tenantIdentifier + "]",
                    se
            );
        }
        return connection;
    }

    @Override
    public void releaseConnection(String tenantIdentifier, Connection connection) throws SQLException {
        try {
            String Query = String.format(AppConstants.DEFAULT_SCHEMA, tenantIdentifier);
            connection.createStatement().executeQuery(Query);
        } catch (SQLException se) {
            throw new HibernateException(
                    "Could not change schema for connection [" + tenantIdentifier + "]",
                    se
            );
        }
        connection.close();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supportsAggressiveRelease() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isUnwrappableAs(Class unwrapType) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public <T> T unwrap(Class<T> unwrapType) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories
public class ApplicationConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    JpaProperties jpaProperties;

    @Autowired
    TenantInterceptor tenantInterceptor;

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(tenantInterceptor);
    }


    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().username(AppConstants.USERNAME).password(AppConstants.PASS)
                .url(AppConstants.URL)
                .driverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver").build();
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
        return new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource, MultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl multiTenantConnectionProviderImpl, CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver currentTenantIdentifierResolver) {
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();

        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect");
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
        properties.put("hibernate.ddl-auto", "update");
        properties.put("hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation", "true");
        properties.put("show-sql", "true");
        properties.put("hikari.maximum-pool-size", "3");
        properties.put("hibernate.default_schema", "master");
        properties.put("maximum-pool-size", "2");

        if (dataSource instanceof HikariDataSource) {
            ((HikariDataSource) dataSource).setMaximumPoolSize(3);
        }

        properties.put(Environment.MULTI_TENANT, MultiTenancyStrategy.SCHEMA);
        properties.put(Environment.MULTI_TENANT_CONNECTION_PROVIDER, multiTenantConnectionProviderImpl);
        properties.put(Environment.MULTI_TENANT_IDENTIFIER_RESOLVER, currentTenantIdentifierResolver);
        properties.put(Environment.FORMAT_SQL, true);


        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSource);

        em.setPackagesToScan("com.saas");
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter());
        em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);

        return em;
    }
}
```

```
@Component
public class TenantResolver implements CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver {


    private static final ThreadLocal<String> TENANT_IDENTIFIER = new ThreadLocal<>();

    public static void setTenantIdentifier(String tenantIdentifier) {
        TENANT_IDENTIFIER.set(tenantIdentifier);
    }

    public static void reset() {
        TENANT_IDENTIFIER.remove();
    }

    @Override
    public String resolveCurrentTenantIdentifier() {
        String currentTenant = TENANT_IDENTIFIER.get() != null ? TENANT_IDENTIFIER.get() : AppConstants.DEFAULT_SCHEMA;
        return currentTenant;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean validateExistingCurrentSessions() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

On successful injection of TenantId by the TenantResolver, the entityManager should be able to store the entities into the corresponding tenant schema in database. That is, if we create an object of an entity and persist same in db, it should be successfully saved in db. But in my case, entities are not getting saved into any schema other than the default one.

Update 1: I was able to do multi-tenant schema switching using mysql 8.0.12. Still not able to do it with postgres.

Answer (score 0):

you should be using AbstractRoutingDataSource to achieve this, it does all the magic behind the scenes, there are many examples online and you can find one at https://www.baeldung.com/spring-abstract-routing-data-source

Answer (score 0):

In your Class "ApplicationConfiguration.java";

You have to remove this "properties.put("hibernate.default_schema", "master");", Why because of when ever your changing the schema it's able to change but when it's reach this line again and again set the default schema

I hope you got the answer

Thank you all

Take care!